# How to limit the user upto only three wrong otp entries

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am making my user enter an otp that he recieves in his email. But somehow I am unable to make the loop that will restrict him to enter the wrong otp only 3 times. If he enters the otp wrong for the third time his username will be deleted. this is the code that I wrote

```
def registerpage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        get_otp = request.POST.get('otp')
        if get_otp:
            get_user= request.POST.get('user')
            user = User.objects.get(username=get_user)

            if int(get_otp) == UserOtp.objects.filter(user= user).last().otp:
                user.is_active = True
                user.save()
                messages.success(request,'Login to complete the registration process.')
                return redirect('login')
            
            else:
               
                messages.error(request, f'OTP entered is wrong')
                return render(request, 'register.html', {'otp': True, 'user': user})



        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        username = request.POST['email']
        password1= request.POST['password']
        password2= request.POST['con_password']
        email= request.POST['email']
        last_name= request.POST['join_as']

        if password1==password2:
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'UserID already exists')
                return redirect('register')
            elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'Email already exists')
                return redirect('register')
            else:    
                user=User.objects.create_user(username= username.lower(), password= password1, email= email.lower(), first_name= first_name.upper(), last_name=last_name)
                user.is_active = False
                user.save()
                user_otp = random.randint(100000, 999999)
                UserOtp.objects.create(user =  user, otp = user_otp)
                mess = f"Hello, {user.first_name}, \nYour OTP is {user_otp}\n Thanks!"

                send_mail(
                    "Welcome to Solve Litigation - Verify your Email",   #subject
                    mess,  #message
                    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,  # sender
                    [user.email],           #reciever
                    fail_silently= False
                )

                return render(request, 'register.html', {'otp': True, 'user': user})


        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Password and Confirm Password not matching')
            return redirect('register') 

      
       
    
    else:
        return render(request, 'register.html')
```

**models.py**

```
class UserOtp(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    otp = models.IntegerField()
```

I tried to implement while and for loop but my logic was not correct may be and I did not get the desired results so I removed the loops for the time being.

Comment: Can you share your `UserOtp` model?

Comment: Please [edit] the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the number of times the `UserOtp` has been wrong with an integer field:

```
class UserOtp(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    otp = models.IntegerField()
    wrongs = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

In case the last `UserOtp` for a given user has `wrongs=2` and the otp is wrong again, one can remove the `user` object:

```
from django.db.models import F

# ⋮

if get_otp:
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['user'])
    lastotp = UserOtp.objects.filter(user= user).last()
    if int(get_otp) == lastotp.otp:
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        messages.success(request,'Login to complete the registration process.')
        return redirect('login')
    elif lastotp.wrongs >= 2:
        user.delete()
        return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        lastotp.wrongs = F('wrongs') + 1
        lastotp.save(force_update=True, update_fields=['wrongs'])
        messages.error(request, f'OTP entered is wrong')
        return render(request, 'register.html', {'otp': True, 'user': user})
```

In case the attempt thus fails, it will increase the `wrongs` field by one. If the `wrongs` field has two attempts and the OTP match is wrong again, we use `user.delete()` to delete the user.

This view however has a security hole: a user can remove other user accounts, simply by making forged POST requests with the same user. If Alice for example wants to remove Bob, she only has to make three requests to the view with Bob as `user` field, and then Bob's account will be removed.

Comment: So what do you recomend sir, shall I not implement this auto delete procedure??

Comment: @RitankarBhattacharjee: I think that in case it required three or more attempts, you should throttle the IP(s) that make POST requests, or for example send a new mail with a different OTP, or a combination of these two.